# How to detect the text above lines using OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I am interested in detecting lines (which I managed to figure out using hough transform) and the text above it.

My test image is below:
[image: Test Image]

The code I have written is below. ( I have edited so that I can loop through the coordinates of each line)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread('test3.jpg')
#img=cv2.resize(img,(500,500))
imgGray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
imgEdges=cv2.Canny(imgGray,100,250)
imgLines= cv2.HoughLinesP(imgEdges,1,np.pi/180,230, minLineLength = 700, maxLineGap = 100)
imgLinesList= list(imgLines)

a,b,c=imgLines.shape
line_coords_list = []
for i in range(a):
    line_coords_list.append([(int(imgLines[i][0][0]), int(imgLines[i][0][1])), (int(imgLines[i][0][2]), int(imgLines[i][0][3]))])

print(line_coords_list)#[[(85, 523), (964, 523)], [(85, 115), (964, 115)], [(85, 360), (964, 360)], [(85, 441), (964, 441)], [(85, 278), (964, 278)], [(85, 197), (964, 197)]]

roi= img[int(line_coords_list[0][0][1]): int(line_coords_list[0][1][1]), int(line_coords_list[0][0][0]) : int(line_coords_list[0][1][0])]
print(roi) # why does this print an empty list?
cv2.imshow('Roi NEW',roi)
```

Now I just don't know how to detect the region of interest above those lines. Is it possible to say crop out each line and have images say roi_1 , roi_2 , roi_n where each roi is the text above the first line, the text above the second line etc?

I would like the output to be something like this.

Comment: Apply morphology to a thresholded image and get the contours. Use the contours to extract each line of text. If long lines remain from the dotted lines on the page, then filter the contours by width or by height. See for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61198983/segmenting-image-files-with-text-and-pictures-into-blocks/61199584#61199584

Comment: @fmw42 - Thanks for that, however it detects all text. How do i go about detecting only the above the dotted lines?

Comment: Discard the top line of text.

Comment: Yes, I just need the text above the lines? Also how do I go about filtering the contours by width or height? I know how to find contours and filtering the lengths

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert to gray
- Threshold (OTSU) so that text is white on black background
- Apply morphology dilate with horizontal kernel to blur text in a line together
- Apply morphology open with a vertical kernel to remove the thin lines from the dotted lines
- Get the contours
- Find the contour that has the lowest Y bounding box value (top-most box)
- Draw all the bounding boxes on the input except for the topmost one
- Save results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread("text_above_lines.jpg")

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold the grayscale image
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# use morphology erode to blur horizontally
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (151, 3))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)

# use morphology open to remove thin lines from dotted lines
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 17))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# find contours
cntrs = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cntrs = cntrs[0] if len(cntrs) == 2 else cntrs[1]

# find the topmost box
ythresh = 1000000
for c in cntrs:
    box = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    x,y,w,h = box
    if y < ythresh:
        topbox = box
        ythresh = y

# Draw contours excluding the topmost box
result = img.copy()
for c in cntrs:
    box = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    if box != topbox:
        x,y,w,h = box
        cv2.rectangle(result, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("text_above_lines_threshold.png", thresh)
cv2.imwrite("text_above_lines_morph.png", morph)
cv2.imwrite("text_above_lines_lines.jpg", result)

#cv2.imshow("GRAY", gray)
cv2.imshow("THRESH", thresh)
cv2.imshow("MORPH", morph)
cv2.imshow("RESULT", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thresholded image:

[image]

Morphology image:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot fmw42.

Quick question: I am having trouble understanding where the code or parameters are in order to control the text above the line and the text without the line. How does it know that "What planet do we live in? does not have a dotted line?

Comment: I simply discarded the line closest to the top. I assumed each page had a question at the top. So the first line would always be the question.

Comment: Ahh, that explains why it fails when I added two question on top of each other. Nevertheless, I've learnt a lot from your help. Now i just need to figure out how to create bounding boxes for text above the line without discarding the line closest to the top.

Answer (score 1):

You have detected the lines. Now you have to split your image into regions between the lines using `y` coordinate and then search for the black pixels (words) on the white background (paper).

Building a histogram along the `x` and `y` axes will likely give you the area of interest you're looking for.

---

Just to answer your questions in the comments, for example, if you have an image `img` and area of the interest with `y` coordinates (100,200) spanning the whole width of the image, you may crop that area down and search for anything there like this:

```
cropped = img[100:200,5:-5]  # crop a few pixels off in x-direction just in case
```

Now the search:

```
top, left = 10000, 10000
bottom, right = 0, 0
for i in range(cropped.shape[0]) :
    for j in range(cropped.shape[1]) :
        if cropped[i][j] < 200 :    # black?
            top = min( i, top)
            bottom = max( i, bottom)
            left = min( j, left)
            right = max( j, right)
```

Or something along the lines...

Comment: @ lenik - Can i have a little more guidance, I am new to using opencv and i've never used the hisogram.

Comment: ```print(imgLines)=

[[[ 38 255 437 255]]

 [[ 38 253 437 253]]

 [[ 38 330 437 330]]

 [[ 38 328 437 328]]

 [[ 38 404 437 404]]

 [[ 38 402 437 402]]

 [[ 38 181 437 181]]

 [[ 38 477 437 477]]

 [[ 38 479 437 479]]

 [[ 38 179 437 179]]

 [[ 38 104 437 104]]]
```
These describe the lines, which I can extract specific regions, but shouldnt there be only 6?

Comment: @AlanJones there are actually only 6, but some of them are repeated for the upper and lower side, like 253 and 255, 402 and 404 etc.

Comment: I have managed to refine the lines and now I get 6. But still having trouble looping through them and extracting the roi.

Comment: @AlanJones in `imgLines` there are clearly 6 lines with the `y` coordinates: 255, 330, 404, 477, 104, 179 -- once you sort them you have an average width of the space allocated for the writing and 6 potential regions to crop and analyze.

Comment: @AlanJones added a few lines of the code to the answer